# Struggling To Use IN Operator and List Parameter In A Dynamic Query. Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports

I was successfully able to use the format `$X{IN, column_name, list_parameter_name}`in a simple report query with `java.util.collection` parameter:

```
Select * from table where $X{IN, column_name, list_parameter_name}
```

However when I try to use `$X{IN, column_name, list_parameter_name}` inside the quotes of a dynamic query I get an error message:

```
declare @sql_query nvarchar(4000)

set @sql_query = 'select * from wo_hdr where $X{IN, wg_name, wg_name_list} ' 

EXEC sp_executesql 

@sql_query

"Error preparing statement for executing the report query: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 1. "
```

I tried putting the parameter inside an SQL variable but it says the parameter type is not supported in a query.

I tried using `$P!{wg_name}` instead but then the list is concatenated with [] brackets instead of () so the query gets a syntax error.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I believe this has to be parsed in ORM, no need to build a dynamic query for it, there is no such a syntax in SQL,
Perhaps ORM will build the query by replacing $X{IN, wg_name, wg_name_list} to
wg_name in ('item1','item2','item3') when you pass the right parameters,

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully using
queries like

```
select t.* from 
Table1 t
where
t.ID in ($P!{MS_RECID})
```

- $P!{...} syntax inserts value as is, no type checks. we better watch out for sql injections.
- type of a parameter **MS_RECID** is a string.
  so default value for the parameter is in double quotes. ([check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U0hb.png))
- when you run report, parameter value shown/entered without quotes which is ok ([check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKghf.png))